# Hive: COUNT features requires GROUP BY when using HAVING, work around?

Tags: count, group-by, hive, having

I'm curious if there is a workaround for excluding a field in the 'group by' statement in Hive?

```
select g.country, count(*) as road_count
from geography g 
join g_street gs on (g.id=gs.id)
group by g.iso_country_code, g.virtual
having (g.virtual='f' or g.virtual is null)
;
```

I do not want the 'g.virtual' in the group by statement because my result should be grouped by country only. Hive requires the 'g.virtual' in the group by statement.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please try to explain what are the logical requirements from your SQL.  It is hard to help if we don't know what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about what you are trying to achieve with the query. Since I see fields in select which don't appear in the group by statement. The only suggestion that I can give is if you plan to put a restriction on geography table then you can place a where clause before joining it with g_street and then group by on the required fields.

Here is an example :

```
select g.iso_country_code, count(*)
from geography g 
where g.virtual='f' or g.virtual is null
join g_street gs on (g.id=gs.id)
group_by g.iso_country_code
```